# Docker python2.7 error: ImportError: cannot import name _remove_dead_weakref

Tags: python, python-2.7, docker

I have a simple Dockerfile which runs an python app

```
FROM python:2.7

RUN addgroup eugene && useradd -u 52712 -g eugene -ms /bin/bash eugene

RUN mkdir /data && chown eugene:eugene /data
VOLUME /data
WORKDIR /workspace

# where bedrock code will be
ADD . /data

# Install any needed packages specified in requirements.txt
RUN pip install --trusted-host repoproxy-rtp.eng.netapp.com --index-url http://repoproxy-rtp.eng.netapp.com:8081/artifactory/api/pypi/python-package-index/simple -r /data/requirements.txt

USER eugene
# Run app.py when the cotainer launches
CMD ["python", "/data/app.py"]
```

It doesnt seem to be able to import multiprocessing.py?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/app.py", line 13, in <module>
    import multiprocessing
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/__init__.py", line 65, in <module>
    from multiprocessing.util import SUBDEBUG, SUBWARNING
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/util.py", line 37, in <module>
    import weakref
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/weakref.py", line 14, in <module>
    from _weakref import (
ImportError: cannot import name _remove_dead_weakref
```

any idea how to resolve this issue? I have no issues running app.py outside of container

Comment: It seems a problem about your python environment. If you search it in google, almost all answers lead to reinstalling python.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and still looking for a valid solution. But at the current moment I find some hint to make it works:

Looks like environment inside of Docker can't use python command by default. So we can go this way (and it works in my case):

```
RUN bash -c "RUN pip install --trusted-host repoproxy-rtp.eng.netapp.com --index-url http://repoproxy-rtp.eng.netapp.com:8081/artifactory/api/pypi/python-package-index/simple -r /data/requirements.txt"
```

The idea of this hint I got from here:
https://github.com/sclorg/s2i-python-container/issues/345

P.S. I'm still trying to find the way just to "turn on: python in Dockerfile...